# C#: System.Security.Authentication.AuthenticationException: The remote certificate is invalid according to the validation procedure

Tags: c#, api, exception, httprequest, httpresponse

I made this method to make a POST request to an API:

```
 public async Task Login2Async()
    {
        
        var body = new 
        {
            username = "string",
            password = "string",
            clientName = "string",
            authorizationToken = "string",
            siteId = "string",
            siteName = "string",
            clientId = "string",
            clientVersion = "string",
            accessToken = "string"
        };

        var json = JsonSerializer.Serialize(body);

        var content = new StringContent(json, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
        var httpClient = new HttpClient();
        var result = await httpClient.PostAsync("https://api_ip/endpoint", content);
        WriteLine(result.StatusCode);
    }
```

And then I'm calling it in the Main method as such:

```
static async Task Main(string[] args)
    {
        var webhook = new AccWebEndpointConnector("localhost", 8000);
        await webhook.Login2Async();

    }
```

but I'm getting this stack trace and I can't understand why.

```
    Unhandled exception. System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: The SSL connection could not be established, see inner exception.
 ---> System.Security.Authentication.AuthenticationException: The remote certificate is invalid according to the validation procedure: RemoteCertificateNameMismatch, RemoteCertificateChainErrors
   at System.Net.Security.SslStream.SendAuthResetSignal(ProtocolToken message, ExceptionDispatchInfo exception)
   at System.Net.Security.SslStream.ForceAuthenticationAsync[TIOAdapter](TIOAdapter adapter, Boolean receiveFirst, Byte[] reAuthenticationData, Boolean isApm)
   at System.Net.Http.ConnectHelper.EstablishSslConnectionAsyncCore(Boolean async, Stream stream, SslClientAuthenticationOptions sslOptions, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.ConnectHelper.EstablishSslConnectionAsyncCore(Boolean async, Stream stream, SslClientAuthenticationOptions sslOptions, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.ConnectAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.CreateHttp11ConnectionAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.GetHttpConnectionAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.SendWithRetryAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean async, Boolean doRequestAuth, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.RedirectHandler.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpClient.SendAsyncCore(HttpRequestMessage request, HttpCompletionOption completionOption, Boolean async, Boolean emitTelemetryStartStop, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at ACCWebEndpointConnector.AccWebEndpointConnector.Login2Async() in C:\Users\dfrco\TechWin\ACCWebEndpointConnector\AccWebEndpointConnector.cs:line 111
   at ACCWebEndpointConnector.Program.Main(String[] args) in C:\Users\dfrco\TechWin\ACCWebEndpointConnector\Program.cs:line 12
   at ACCWebEndpointConnector.Program.<Main>(String[] args)
```

I've tried to make the exact same POST request using Postman and it works just fine.

Comment: Are you using a valid certificate? I think the reason Postman works is because it does not validate the certificate at all. https://stackoverflow.com/a/60378113/5308388

Comment: @Riddell, on my side, I'm not. How do I add one? Or how do I make this work just like postman?

Comment: It's saying `RemoteCertificateNameMismatch` which is a sign of an invalid certificate most like an incorrect SAN.

Comment: Usually add following static method to beginning of code solves issue : ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;

Comment: @jdweng, tried it. Didn't work...

Comment: What version of Net are you using?  What is target?  TLS is failing due to certificate.  The certificate has to be loaded on both client and server.  TLS there is a Certificate block where server sends names of possible certificates.  Than client looks up the certificate in the stores. If a certificate with name is not found in client stores the error above will occur.  Postman is working so the certificate is loaded. So the version of Net isn't supporting the TLS version (or encryption mode).

Comment: @jdweng I'm using version 5.0.301

Comment: Do you get exactly same error with adding line ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12 |  SecurityProtocolType.Tls13 (I added tls 1.3).  You may need to use a sniffer like wireshark or fiddler and see what version of TLS is being used and check the TLS certificate block from server to client to see the names of the certificate.