# HttpClient consume Web Api with ssl certifcate from IIS

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api

I am ussing NET 6.0 to build a Web Api and a Client application to consume it.

I have deployed the web api into a webservice inside my local network using IIS

The SSL certifate used is the certificate proporcionated by IIS by default

[image: Cerificate]

I get the certificate download it form Google Chrome, then i am making the call to consume the web api as follow

```
internal static async Task<(bool, string, GeneralAnswer<UserAccess>)> UserAccessPost(string alias, string password, WebServiceParams _params)
    {
        try
        {
            string json = JsonSerializer.Serialize(new
            {
                usr_alias = alias,
                usr_password = password
            });

            var data = new StringContent(json, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

            X509Certificate2 Cert = new X509Certificate2("C:\\Users\\egomez\\source\\repos\\Trazo_Registro_Tienda_Administracion _nuevo_webservice\\ClassLibraryWebServiceConnect\\Operations\\Certificates\\WMSvc-SHA2-GTLTATSW01W16.crt");

            HttpClientHandler handler = new HttpClientHandler();
            handler.ClientCertificates.Add(Cert);
            handler.SslProtocols = SslProtocols.Tls12 | SslProtocols.Tls11 | SslProtocols.Tls | SslProtocols.Ssl3 | SslProtocols.Ssl2;

            var client = new HttpClient(handler);

            client.Timeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(_params._TIMEOUT_WEB_SERVICE);

            var response = await client.PostAsync(_params._IP_WEB_SERVICE + "api/Access/", data);

            if (response.StatusCode == System.Net.HttpStatusCode.OK)
            {
                var result = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

                return (
                    true,
                    "Respuesta del servidor obtenida con exito.",
                    JsonSerializer.Deserialize<GeneralAnswer<UserAccess>>(result));
            }
            else
            {
                return (
                    false,
                    "Error al obtener credenciales. Estatus: " + response.StatusCode,
                    null);
            }
            
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return (
                false,
                "Error, Excepcion: " + ex.Message.ToLower(),
                new GeneralAnswer<UserAccess>());
        }
    }
```

But i am getting this exception

[image]

**EDIT**

I found a form to make it work. Because this is untrustful certicate and there is not SAN.

I added this fucntion to trust in the certifacte when the sha code is teh correct.

```
    internal static bool ValidateServerCertificate(HttpRequestMessage message, X509Certificate2 certificate, X509Chain chain, SslPolicyErrors policy)
            {
                return certificate.GetCertHashString() == "88D664F25FEE8A99CDA8B1041B708AE6808B061D" ? true : false;
            }
```

Then in the methoed of post called it this way

```
internal static async Task<(bool, string, GeneralAnswer<UserAccess>)> UserAccessPost(string alias, string password, WebServiceParams _params)
        {
            try
            {
                string json = JsonSerializer.Serialize(new
                {
                    usr_alias = alias,
                    usr_password = password
                });

                var data = new StringContent(json, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

                HttpClientHandler handler = new HttpClientHandler();
                handler.ServerCertificateCustomValidationCallback = Certificate.ValidateServerCertificate;

                var client = new HttpClient(handler);

                client.Timeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(_params._TIMEOUT_WEB_SERVICE);

                var response = await client.PostAsync(_params._IP_WEB_SERVICE + "api/Access/", data);

                if (response.StatusCode == System.Net.HttpStatusCode.OK)
                {
                    var result = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

                    return (
                        true,
                        "Respuesta del servidor obtenida con exito.",
                        JsonSerializer.Deserialize<GeneralAnswer<UserAccess>>(result));
                }
                else
                {
                    return (
                        false,
                        "Error al obtener credenciales. Estatus: " + response.StatusCode,
                        null);
                }
                
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return (
                    false,
                    "Error, Excepcion: " + ex.Message.ToLower(),
                    new GeneralAnswer<UserAccess>());
            }
        }
```

Comment: according to the exception there is a naming mismatch have you checked if the names are equal? Also make sure you have added the certificates to the correct trusted root

Comment: Where i can check the name of the certificate i have no created by my own is a defualt one?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60378113/18278998 check this answer out it might help you solve your issue

Comment: IIS doesn't have a "default" certificate. If you use a self-signed certificate, it's invalid by definition as no other machine will trust it. What you did is only *slightly* better than disabling validation completely. The *real* solution is to install a valid certificate. Let's Encrypt offers free certificates for public sites. In an intranet, there will be a Trusted CA service that can issue certificates trusted by any machine that trusts that CA. In a Windows Active Directory Domain for example, the Certificate Services role does just that

Comment: The "solution" you posted isn't a solution at all anyway, as no client except yours will trust this certificate. For development purposes only, you can add the site's certificate to your machine's trusted certificate so you don't get errors.

Comment: When you installed IIS, it did generate a few certificates for different purposes, but none of them should be used for your own sites like the other comment indicated.